# mysql sphinx generate unique id

Tags: mysql, search, sphinx

I have my database segmented in 8 parts, where each part contains database with table user_data, for better search performance im using sphinx to index all those data but im come accross one problem ... since table user_data dont have any unique field to represent each row but its a 1 to many table i have trouble to run my sphinx index correctly since it requires unique id and this way resolve in duplicate ids ... any idea how can i workaround this? or generate unique id throught all sub indexes from different segments?

example:

```
SELECT user_id, item_id, info
FROM user_data
```

Which returns something like:

```
+----------+-----------------------+
| user_id  | item_id    | info     |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 10       | 151        | asdf     |
| 10       | 152        | test     |
| 11       | 151        | 545      |
| 12       | 151        | sdfsd    |
| 12       | 152        | eewwe    |
| 12       | 153        | dfsd     |
```

but i have to get

```
+----------+-----------------------------+
| user_id  | item_id    | info     | id  |
+----------+-----------------------------+
| 10       | 151        | asdf     | 1   |
| 10       | 152        | test     | 2   |
| 11       | 151        | 545      | 3   |
| 12       | 151        | sdfsd    | 4   |
| 12       | 152        | eewwe    | 5   |
| 12       | 153        | dfsd     | 6   |
```

of course id must be unique throght all segments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you should set before action query to set your variable

```
sql_query_pre = SET @a := 1;
```

then use this variable to get fictional auto increment

```
sql_query = SELECT @a := @a + 1 AS id, user_id, item_id, info FROM user_data
```

Comment: should be `SET @a := 0` so that the first row is actually 1

Comment: Can you show this working for multiple tables, so I understand it correctly.  I'm looking at the option below this and I understand how it works, but I don't with this one.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with Sphinx, but if you're looking to create ids that are unique across tables, in your case:

1. One option is to use a [UUID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid) as a unique index on all the tables -- the chances of them colliding are minute.
2. Another option is, if you know the max size of a table, to only use numbers in that range plus an offset. E.g., Table 1's ids: 1 - 10000, Table 2's ids: 10001 - 20000, etc. You can even set the `id` fields to be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and set their start numbers at the beginning of the particular range.

Comment: Why do you have to use an integer?

Comment: Sphinx requires an integer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this while indexing:

`SELECT user_id + 10 * 1 AS id, 1 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_1`

... adding a `segment_id`. You would have eight of these, so the indexing query would look something like:

```
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 1 AS id, 1 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_1
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 2 AS id, 2 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_2
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 3 AS id, 3 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_3
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 4 AS id, 4 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_4
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 5 AS id, 5 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_5
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 6 AS id, 6 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_6
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 7 AS id, 7 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_7
UNION
SELECT (user_id + 10) * 8 AS id, 8 AS segment_id, itme_id, info FROM user_data_8
```

Then when you query sphinx and get back the IDs, just undo the arithmetic by dividing the `id` by `segment_id` and subtracting `10`. This way all the ids will be unique within sphinx. Just make sure the attribute type can handle the size of the ids you'll be indexing.

Comment: this is possible but i find a better solution

Answer (score 0):

As proposed in another answer saying to use UUID. But sphinx can not use UUID as id. You will need an INT. Therefor use UUID_SHORT and then you have a unique integer (for mysql). If this does not work out of the box (e.g. if you aare using Ubuntu-11.04), you will get an error like this:

```
WARNING: DOCID_MAX document_id, skipping
```

You will need to compile sphinx source with –enable-id64, or just go to sphinx website and get an up to date package (which is compiled with –enable-id64). A more complete example of this indexing method is given in [this blog entry](http://www.os-cms.net/blog/view/23/unique-id-with-multiple-tables-using-sphinx)

Answer (score -2):

We are using crc32(uuid_short()) for 32 bit implementations of sphinx. This works, most of the time! Ofc. one cannot rely upon a 32 bit digest of a